# Bootstrap DateTimePicker Close Button Position

Tags: eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using Eonasdan Bootstrap-datetimepicker in my project ! Is there any option to change the position of close button from top to bottom ? (Not  Widget Position). I searched in there documentation but I cant find it.

Thanks in  advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use the [`toolbarPlacement`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#toolbarplacement) option for this.

> Default: 'default'
>
> Accepts: 'default', 'top', 'bottom'

```js
$('#myDatepicker').datetimepicker({
  toolbarPlacement: 'bottom',
  showClose: true,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/25c11d79/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<br/>
<!--Space for the fiddle-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='myDatepicker'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```